# how to define a "select *" JPA predicate with eager fetch?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i have the following 3 entities (note the hierarchy of lazy collections):

```
@Entity
public class ObjectEntity {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   Set<ObjectInstanceEntity> instances;
}

@Entity
public class ObjectInstanceEntity {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   Set<ObjectInstanceClientEntity> clients;
}

@Entity
public class ObjectInstanceClientEntity {
   //nothing special
}
```

and i also have the spring-data-jpa repository for the root entity:

```
public interface ObjectEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<ObjectEntity, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ObjectEntity>{
}
```

im trying use the `Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)` method on `JpaSpecificationExecutor` to bring in a page's worth of `ObjectEntity`s while eagerly loading all the collections (instances and instances.clients). this is where im stuck:

```
private final Specification<ObjectEntity> spec = new Specification<ObjectEntity>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ObjectEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        root.fetch("instances", JoinType.LEFT);
        root.fetch("instances.clients", JoinType.LEFT); //this doesnt work
        return cb.; //what do i put here? any(null) ?
    }
};
```

whats the correct way to construct the predicate so that all lazy colelctions are brought in?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fetch() method returns a [Fetch](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Fetch.html%20[-]) object that could be used as "root" of a new fetch().

The fetch is stored into the Root object, you don't have to return it.

In your case:

```
private final Specification<ObjectEntity> spec = new Specification<ObjectEntity>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ObjectEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        root.fetch("instances", JoinType.LEFT).fetch("clients", JoinType.LEFT); //this should work
    }
};
```

Comment: You haven't specified return value for the toPredicate method.

Comment: it is not a mistake, it's not required to return the object.

Comment: does it compile then?